# Lost all my contacts after flashing custom rom (sg2)

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2, sync, rom-flashing, google-account

I got a Galaxy S2 as an upgrade from my HTC Hero around January this year. My phone contacts have always been synced to my Gmail account and the backup worked since I got all my contacts on my SGS2 from my HTC Hero. However, I flashed a custom ROM on my SGS2 and since then only 14 of my contacts have been retrieved. When I try to manually sync the phone with Google it still only shows the 14 contacts. I visited http://google.com/contacts and to my surprise I only have the 14 contacts there as well.

How can I fix this problem? Do I have to flash it back to custom rom or is there any other way?

Comment: Next time check google.com/contacts . By default your contacts are stored in the Google's cloud

Answer (score 1):

Via your desktop computer, go to the Contacts section in Gmail. Click the MORE button and then RESTORE CONTACTS.

You'll be shown a dialog box where you can pick a particular time to restore to within the past 30 days.

That should restore your contact data.

After that just sync your device.

Comment: Thank you spark for your help! But that's not how I got my contacts back. I got my contacts back by importing from my SIM-card... Even though I have always chosen to use google..

Comment: @user27493 Please create a new answer as to how you solved your problem. After that, accept your answer so the question can be completed. :)

Answer (score -1):

The solution is very simple, the problem is that the ROM is just reading the phone contacts and you just have to delete a file!

*Caveat Emptor* Your phone must be rooted

- Go download an app called [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer&hl=en) from Play Store
- Launch *Root Explorer*
- Go to this directory `/data/data/com.android.contacts/shared_preferences`
- then delete `com.android.contacts_preferences.xml`

That's the first part done, remaining part is this, now, go into your Contacts app via home screen or application drawer, tap on *Menu*, then tap on *Import/Export*, then import all the contacts from SIM to phone!

Comment: Can you explain more clearly for the benefit of those who are not native english speakers on this forum, they will have difficulty comprehending, as for text speak, this is *frowned* upon.

Comment: I have taken the liberty in re-editing your poor answer. After editing, this answer is assuming that the OP is rooted, there is no indication of that.